# Certain Database Table fields not saving using cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I've added two new fields to my subscription database table namely `first_name` and `last_name` to table `subscriptions`

But whenever I get my values returned from the form and I try to save them then it's not saving to the database?

My code is as follows

```
$this->data['Subscription']['id'] = $subscription['Subscription']['id']; //To get the primary key
$this->data['Subscription']['first_name']; //Echoes out the name I entered
$this->data['Subscription']['last_name']; //Echoes out the surname I entered
```

Then I call `$this->Subscription->save();` WHICH SAVES ALL OTHER FIELDS except the fields I've newly added to the table, I tried $this->Subscription->set($this->data['Subscription']); and also nothing wants to save?

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here? Any help will be higly appreciated!!!!

Comment: I don't see where you are assigning values to first_name and last_name. Can you post that code? Try using `debug($this->data);` before the save to see what is actually in that array.

Comment: can you post part of the view where the data is entered? have you tried to look if this->data has indeed the first_name and last_name?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you run the app with debug 0 you need to delete the cache in /tmp because the database schema is cached by CakePHP.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you forgot to add $this->data to save, you must save your data like so:

```
$this->Subscription->save( $this->data );
```